# Refactor my ruby twitter gem code

Tags: ruby, twitter, refactoring, rubygems

I have written some ruby code which archives tweets but I have a couple of questions.
1. My code seems inefficient, can you help me refactor it?
2. I don't really understand how to handle the twitter error.  I'd like to print out the specific error which it is throwing, not just my standard text.
3. I don't understand how to use the rate limit status code.  My code always spits out the exact same thing: "150 Twitter API request(s) remaining for the next 59 minutes and 59 seconds"
Thanks!

```
require 'twitter'

count = 1
query = "hello"
res = Twitter.search(query, :rpp => 1, :result_type => "recent", :page => 1).results
search_id = res.first.id

loop do
  begin
    res = Twitter.search(query, :rpp => 100, :result_type => "recent", :page => 1, :max_id => search_id).results
    res.each do |status|
      puts "#{status.id}, #{status.created_at}, #{status.from_user}, #{status.text}"

      puts count.to_s
      count = count+1
    end
    search_id = res.last.id-1

  rescue Twitter::Error => e
    rate_limit_status = Twitter.rate_limit_status
    puts "#{rate_limit_status.remaining_hits} Twitter API request(s) remaining for the next #{((rate_limit_status.reset_time - Time.now) / 60).floor} minutes and #{((rate_limit_status.reset_time - Time.now) % 60).round} seconds"

    puts "Error: No more tweets to collect."
    puts e.inspect
    puts "Last tweet collected at #{res.last.created_at}"
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: for one thing change `while(true)` to `loop` cause it looks nicer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm not going to rewrite your code for you (nor should you expect anyone to do that on SO), but I will point out a few issues and try and explain a couple of things:

1. First, you're calling `Twitter.search` before entering your loop, and then you're immediately calling it again, discarding the first batch of results in the process.
2. You should look at the documentation for [rate_limit_status](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/rate_limit_status). Since you don't appear to be using an authenticated user, this call is simply returning the rate limit for your IP address, which is unlikely to change except for the fact that...
3. You are calling the search request repeatedly without any offtime, possibly thousands of times per minute. If you actually need this sort of immediate result from the API, you should look [Twitter's Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis). Otherwise, you should toss a call to `sleep(x)` into your loop. Abuse of the API is likely to get your IP blocked, and it's also just impolite.
4. To get the details of the exception, try something like this:

   ```
   rescue Twitter::Error => e
     puts "Oops I messed up"
     puts e.inspect
   end
   ```

   and while you're at it, read up on [ruby exceptions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot.  1. I know.  I need to set up the correct max_id for the first search.  I only throw away one tweet as the :rpp is set to 1.  Didn't think this would be a problem.  2. I have noticed it does actually change if I run my code enough times.  Would you recommend I login with my credentials to do these queries even though it's not necessary? 3. It takes about 15 seconds to print out 100 tweets, so it's only a couple of calls per minute.  This is the only way I know of to overcome the 1500 tweet limit for a standard search.  After I collect initial tweets I can set up streaming.

Comment: Looks like Twitter is going to require authorization in all cases pretty soon, so I would go ahead and add it. Good luck with your code!